why st_dev in stat structure is somewhat difference with the output of the command stat
i use stat() system call, and st_dev and st_rdev gives me somethong about device id that is fe02 and 0
command line stat gives me Device: fe02h/65026d
why there is a difference? or is my code wrong?
here is mystat.c code
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int args,char * argv[]){
    struct stat buffers;
    int status;
    status = stat("/home/debian/",&buffers);
    printf("return from stat(): %d\n",status);
    printf("/home/debian\n");
    printf("ID of device containing file: %x\n",buffers.st_dev);
    printf("Inode number: %d\n",buffers.st_ino);
    printf("File type and mode: %o\n",buffers.st_mode);
    printf("Number of hard links: %d\n",buffers.st_nlink);
    printf("User ID of owner: %d\n",buffers.st_uid);
    printf("Group ID of owner: %d\n",buffers.st_gid);
    printf("Device ID: %x\n",buffers.st_rdev);
    printf("Total size, in bytes: %d\n",buffers.st_size);
    printf("Block size for filesystem I/O: %d\n",buffers.st_blksize);
    printf("Number of 512B blocks allcated: %d\n",buffers.st_blocks);
    return 0;
}

here is ./mystat output
return from stat(): 0
/home/debian
ID of device containing file: fe02
Inode number: 407113
File type and mode: 40755
Number of hard links: 13
User ID of owner: 1000
Group ID of owner: 1000
Device ID: 0
Total size, in bytes: 4096
Block size for filesystem I/O: 4096
Number of 512B blocks allcated: 8

and this is stat /home/debian/ output
  File: /home/debian/
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fe02h/65026d    Inode: 407113      Links: 13
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  debian)   Gid: ( 1000/  debian)
Access: 2024-12-11 03:40:38.782991622 -0800
Modify: 2024-12-11 03:40:33.583142964 -0800
Change: 2024-12-11 03:40:33.583142964 -0800
 Birth: 2022-09-25 14:08:13.430517983 -0700

